# How can I make a PNR for flight and hotel in a single request in Sabre?

Tags: sabre

As of now I can issue a request using flight and hotel alone. Is there a way I can set a PNR containing hotel and flight using passenger details?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment a combination of OTA_HotelResLLSRQ and EnhancedAirBookRQ /  OTA_AirBookLLSRQ can be used to book hotel and flights.

There's no single service to accomplish both in a single call right now.

PassengerDetails can be used to add required PNR information such as passenger names, contact, ticket time limit, etc.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I do a separate request for OTA_AirBookLLSRQ and passenger details how can I use passenger details to queue OTA_AirBookLLSRQ response

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'queue OTA_AirBookLLSRQ response'?
Can you briefly explain what you are trying to accomplish with those two services and calls in sequence?

Comment: I wanted to book for flight using OTA_AirBookLLSRQ after booking after booking how am I supposed to add my flight details in Passenger details for PNR submission to queue.

Comment: If you use the same binary sec. token in both calls (OTA_AirBookLLSRQ and PDetails), flights added via OTA_AirBookLLSRQ will be present in your work area, and from the call to PDetails you can add the rest of the required  information (passenger names, contact, ticket time limit, received from etc) and End the transaction to complete a PNR.

Regarding queues, PDetails also has PostProcessing/QueuePlaceRQ node that allows queue placing the PNR after it is completed.


See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195825/sabre-passenger-details-production-resources to get info about PDetails.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful Info. Now I somehow understand the process. Regarding QueuePlaceRQ I tried to put it inside passenger details but i'm getting an error. It says invalid content starting from QueuePlaceRQ. Any Idea on this?