# Sabre Passenger Details production resources

Tags: sabre

I Need Prod Samples of Passenger details. Until now I cant open passenger details resources. If you guys do have access to these could you email me the entire samples?

Thanks

Comment: Just go to Sabre's developer site. And **DON'T PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS IN THE QUESTION**. Even if SO was a discussion forum (it isn't), exposing your address to every spammer really isn't the best idea. Asking for people to email you the answer instead of posting it here is just as bad - this helps no-one. No-one will be able to correct mistakes in the samples, and people that have the same question won't know the answer

Comment: Oh.. my bad.. thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have access to the PassengerDetails resource page you have to have a webservices contract.

You can go to the [contact us page](https://developer.sabre.com/contact) and select the option *I want to become a Sabre customer* for more information

Comment: I have requested it already to add my email in webservices. I just cant wait to get this done. Dont have any guides what other details to put in passenger details.

Comment: Webservices support does not modify users on DevStudio.
From what I know, when you register on the site, you have to put your IPCC and your email address has to be in the webservices order for you to be enabled within the period mentioned after the registration (I believe 48 hours)